# Whats the difference between a Cloudpage and microsite in Salesforce Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, microsites

My understanding is a cloudpage is a way to create a webpage using html/css/js.
From what I can see a microsite is the same thing.
Is there a difference?

Comment: Nothing difference in current version of marketing cloud account doesn't contain microsite pages

Answer (score 1):

So when you say Microsite, there are two versions of Microsites -- the Classic version or CloudPages Microsites. Both essentially just tie together landing pages/Cloud Pages in a site map.

The classic version of Microsites uses landing pages in classic content. CloudPages Microsites is the *newer* version.

Similar to **Content Builder** versus Classic Content, [CloudPages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_cloudpages.htm&type=5) uses a WYSIWYG editor within the tool

Answer (score 1):

A microsite is a collection of one or more landing pages hosted in your account. Use a microsite to contain information beyond what you include in an email. For example, you can create a microsite to contain a lead-generation form, an opt-in subscriber form, or to direct subscribers to more information about a corporate initiative. A larger distinction is that allows to host landing pages in your designated account.